# autocompletar textbox/combobox y gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, autocompletar

Me rindo, no he encontrado respuesta, soy principiante en C# y tengo una clase donde cada fin de semana el maestro nos deja una tarea tipo reto, y esta vez fue hacer un buscador, pero usando los datos generados vía código de una sola columna del gridview (los datos ya estaban, solo tengo que escribir el código del buscador) y se supone que lo que debe ocurrir es que escribes en el textbox una letra y te despliega las palabras que empiecen con dicha letra dentro del gridview... tras una larga búsqueda encontré el siguiente código que ni siquiera se si es el correcto, internet no sirve de mucho porque los tutoriales son con base en SQL

```
string[] productListSearch = new string[InventoryTable.Rows.Count];


        for (int unitP = 0; unitP < InventoryTable.Rows.Count; unitP++)
        {
            productListSearch[unitP] = Convert.ToString(InventoryTable.Rows[unitP].Cells[0].Value);
        }
        InventorySearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        InventorySearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        InventorySearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(productListSearch);
```

Comment: Ya lo resolví, me faltaban unas lineas

Answer (score 0):

Aqui esta resuelto

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] productListSearch = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
        for (int unitP = 0; unitP < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; unitP++)
        {
            productListSearch[unitP] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[unitP].Cells[0].Value);
        }
        var fuente = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        fuente.AddRange(productListSearch);
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = fuente;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
```

Comment: Si tu pregunta esta resuelta, marca tu respuesta como la solucion a tu pregunta :)